# Timing of resolving of promises and handling browser events

Tags: javascript, events, promise, ecmascript-6

Consider the following code written in ES6:

```
function waitForMessage() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        function handler(event) {
            resolve(event);
            window.removeEventListener('message', handler);
        };
        window.addEventListener('message', handler); 
    });
}

function loop(event) {
    // do something (synchronous) with event
    waitForMessage().then(loop);
}
waitForMessage().then(loop);
```

In this piece of code, `waitForMessage` installs an event handler waiting for a message to arrive at the current window. Once it has arrived, the promise returned by `waitForMessage` is being resolved and the event handler removed.

In `loop`, a new promise is being generated by `waitForMessage` as soon as the job enqueued by resolving the previous promise is being run.

Now my question is whether `loop` may not get all messages posted at window due to a timing problem: If the jobs enqueued by `Promise.prototype.resolve` are not always being run before any tasks enqueued in the browser's event loop, it may be the case that an `message` event is begin dispatched at `window` while there is currently no handler listening for this event.

What does the standard say about the timing of these different types of jobs/tasks, namely resolving the callbacks of promises and the dispatching of events from outside of the ES6 world?

(I just took the `message` event as an example, I am equally interested in other events, like `click` or `popstate` events.)

P.S.: As this has been asked for several times in the comments below, let me describe what I was hoping for with the above code:

I would like to use ES6 features to avoid having to deal too much with callbacks in my code and to make sure that added event listeners are removed in time to avoid memory leaks. Thus I have written something along these lines:

```
const looper = (element, type, generator) => (... args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const iterator = generator(...args);
    const listener = (event) => {
        try {
            let {done, value} = iterator.next(event);
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
            element.removeEventListener(type, listener);
        }
        if (done) {
            resolve(value);
            element.removeEventListener(type, listener);
        }  
    }
    element.addEventListener(type, listener);
    listener();
});

const loop = (element, type, generator) => looper(element, type, generator)();
```

With this code, I can do something like:

```
loop(window, 'message', function *() {
    event = yield;
    // do something synchronous with event
    if (shouldStopHere) {
        return result;
    }
});
```

This code does not suffer from the issues my question is about; only one promise is created and the event handler is only attached and removed once. Removal of the event handler is guaranteed when the inner function returns.

It is well known that generators in ES6 can also be used for handling promises (like the `asyncio` package does in Python 3.4). There is proposal for ES7 to include some sugar for these async functions, namely https://github.com/lukehoban/ecmascript-asyncawait. I was hoping to use this sugar (which is supported by Traceur at the moment) to sugarize my above `loop` function. However, the proposed async functions only deal with promises so I tried to rewrite my loop code in a fashion that produces a result of promises, the result of which I posted at the beginning of my question.

Comment: You're kind of bastardizing promises on this one. Promises should not really be used for events that can happen more than once.

Comment: I fail to see the point why promises should not be used in this case. In any case, the question remains.

Comment: Well, because a Promise is an object that represents some data that will be available in the future, like the result of an asynchronous function call. It's not suited for something that may or may not ever arrive, or something that would arrive more than once.

Comment: Well, technically it should work in chrome but it is unspecified. Also I agree with SecondRikudo - there are similar abstractions (namely RxJS observables) that solve the problem of multiple events arriving. A promise represent _a single value_ and cannot be reused - how are you using the promises you generate here? Where are you opening them? Remember a promise _only resolves once_.

Comment: @Second Rikudo: I agree on that a promise should eventually be resolved or rejected. Insofar, my above code is not complete - in a real piece of code, `waitForMessage` should have a way to reject the promise when listening for further incoming messages should stop. For otherwise, the main loop would run forever.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Each call of `waitForMessage` listens only for one arriving message. As each call of `waitForMessage` creates a new promise, each promise stands for exactly one single value in the future.

Comment: @Marc what advantage does it offer over putting it in an event handler without involving a promise?

Comment: Whatever other issues there are with this approach, I think you need to say `function loop(event) { return waitForMessage().then(loop); }`. Note the `return`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Addressing your specific issue

The behavior of the promise constructor is well defined both in ES6 promises and promise implementations that implement the constructor spec (virtually everything except old jQuery):

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     // ALWAYS runs synchronously
     console.log("Hello"); 
}); 
console.log("World"); // program always logs "Hello World", events will never be missed
```

This is well specified and by design. The use case you are describing is mostly why this behavior was guaranteed to work in the spec.

**Note that while the promise constructor is specified to run synchronously you still have a race condition with the `then`** - http://jsfiddle.net/vko4p6zz/

I don't think promises are the correct abstraction here (see jfriend00's answer) but it might make sense with more context - you can rely on the execution order of the promise constructor. You can see this [in the specification](https://people.mozilla.org/%7Ejorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-promise-executor) - `new Promise` then calls `InitializePromise` which in turn *synchronously* calls the function passed.

#### A possibly better approach.

Just like a promise represents a single value + time, there is an abstraction called an observable that represents multiple values + time. Just like a promise is a functional callback an observable is a functional event emitter. Here is an example using one library (RxJS) - there are several other libraries implementing the concept:

```
var messageStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(window, 'message');
messageStream.subscribe(function(value){
   console.log(value); // unwrapping the event
});
```

In addition to unwrapping with subscribe - you can also `map` events, filter them, `flatMap` them and more - they compose just like promises and are as close as I think you can/should get to promises in this context.

Comment: (Note: while the promise constructor is synchronous the `then` in your loop of course isn't - it's worth clarifying that)

Comment: You talk about `InitializePromise()` in the specification, but I didn't think that was the issue here.  I thought the issue was the timing between when `resolve()` is called and when the `.then()` handler is called.  That is the time that the event handler is not installed so that would be the window to miss events if there's any chance of an event getting processed before the `.then()` handler that is triggered by the call to `resolve()` gets called.  Isn't that the operative issue?

Comment: @jfriend00 to be honest I just really don't like the approach OP is taking with how the promises run. Technically the DOM actually [does specify](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#promises) execution order and [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#dom-window-postmessage).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't follow in either one of those links how the timing of a `.then()` handler being called when `resolve()` is called relates to the timing of an event handler for a previously queued event (e.g. something that was already in the queue at the time `resolve()` was called?

Comment: @Marc if you're just asking if it will never miss messages than of course it will (when two messages are dispatched synchronously) - here is the most trivial example: http://jsfiddle.net/f45a5pdx/

Comment: Interesting to note that I get different results in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f45a5pdx/) in Firefox and Chrome which is likely why this type of code should be avoided.

Comment: @jfriend00 now I'm not even sure who to file a bug against :D The WhatWG mailing list might be the correct place to ask about this - I'm sure Domenic would know.

Comment: Since we now have a documented behavior discrepancy between browsers related to this issue, I think it pretty clearly makes the point that code should not be used that relies on this timing when alternate implementations certainly exist that do not depend upon this issue at all which is the point I was trying to make in my answer and you offered an alternative implementation also that isn't susceptible to this implementation difference.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree which is why my answer says "see jfriend00's answer' :) In general I run from things that involve ambiguous execution order like fire.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: That's a point, namely that my code will miss messages when two of them are dispatched synchronously! This means that the rest of my question, namely in which order processing takes place, becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @Marc I'm not sure how much more me and jfriend00 can stress this fact - promises are not a good fit for your problem here. You should not use them for this scenario - I really don't want to appeal to my or his authority but we've both seen hundreds of questions like this one and can spot the cases pretty well. For a more general reasoning see https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I can see the point now. Thanks for all of your input. I have edited my question and added some motivation, namely to be able to use the proposed ES7 async functions in these kind of situations. So I tried to make a nail a screw just to be able to use a screwdriver.

Comment: Checked this answer (which basically says the same as the other one) for the infomative jsFiddle. I agree that Observable model is the better one; it's possibly a good idea to enlarge the sugar that shall be provided by ES7 async functions to include the case of streams as well... (and not to hard-code the spawn function wrapper).

Comment: @Marc when ES7 will come it will ship with async generators and the `for... on` loop. Don't worry support is on the way :) https://github.com/jhusain/asyncgenerator - your ES7 might look something like this:  https://gist.github.com/benjamingr/e377e2417f803561439b

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69592/discussion-between-marc-and-benjamin-gruenbaum).

Comment: I disagree, promises are fine for pull streams if you don't care about how buffering is done.. it gives async equivalent to `while(data = read(1024))` -> `while(data = yield read(1024))`

Comment: @Esailija your `yield read` effectively yields from an async generator, the promise is just the value yielded here, you're not looping the stream through the promise - you're of course welcome to name your async iterable it any way you'd like.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum generators are unrelated, the equivalent without await async is `read().then(function loop(data){ if(data) return read().then(loop);});` but is much harder to read in comment

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm currently in the process of implementing the async generator proposal with Traceur so that one can experiment with it, spec it, and hopefully include it in ES7.

Answer (score 3):

At best, your current approach would be relying on a precise and consistent implementation of promise `.then()` handlers such they never allowed other queued events to process before they were called.

At worst, you would definitely have a chance at missing events.

If you look at [Benjamin's jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f45a5pdx/) and run it in both Chrome and Firefox, you will see that Firefox misses an event (I don't see a missing event in Chrome).

What is clear is that your current design is simply not a safe design because it relies on implementation details (that may or may not be well specified and may or may not be implemented perfectly even if specified) that your code simply does not need to depend on.  Whether or not some spec says that this might or should work, this is a brittle design that does not need to be susceptible to this issue.

What would make more sense is to base your design on a constantly installed event listener so there is no way you can ever miss an event.  It is probably still possible to use promises with that type of design, but as others have pointed out that is rarely (if ever) a preferred design pattern because promises are not designed for repeated events so you have to continue to create new promises after each event and you will generally find that just using a classic callback for an event handler is a much cleaner way of doing things and takes none of the risks that your current approach is taking.

For example, your proposed code could simply be replaced with this:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    // the synchronous code you mentioned to process the event
});
```

which is simpler and is guaranteed to not have any vulnerability to missing messages that your code might have.  This code is also more consistent with general design patterns for event driven code in common use for a wide variety of events (such as click events that you mentioned).

Comment: So are you saying that the order of processing events and queued promise callbacks is unspecified? Note that I am not talking about Promise implementations in "userland" code but about the native Promises in ES6.

Comment: @Marc - I don't know exactly what is or isn't specified in that regard.  Folks like Benjamin can speak to that.  My point is that it's foolish (in my opinion) to write code that requires a specific specification and a perfect implementation to that specification across all engines that might run your code when such a dependency upon the implementation details is simply not necessary.  This is even more so an issue when you're talking about using a new implementation of a new specification.  In other words, why write brittle code that is sensitive to such details when you don't need to?

Answer (score 3):

> What does the standard say about the timing of these different types of jobs/tasks, namely resolving the callbacks of promises and the dispatching of events from outside of the ES6 world?

- Promises are run in the micro task queue.
- UI Events are run in the macro task queue.

The HTML5 spec mandates that the [micro task queue](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#processing-model-9:task-queue) is fully drained before the macro task queue starts its next task.

The [DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-dom-20131107/#promises) is currently [undergoing changes](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=22296#c25) because they want to refine how observers interleave with promises, but they will remain on the micro task queue.

Comment: This answers my original question.