# XHR OnLoad Promise blocking other OnLoad callbacks

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, es6-promise

I am trying to download files from my server then run Promises on the loaded data.
My issue is that is seems that my Promise are blocking everything for some reason:

It start downloading ALL files, once the first file is downloaded, it blocks others download and run its "onLoad" callback full promise chain, then it keeps downloading the remaining files. Once a new file has completed, it blocks other downloads and run the promise chain and so on.

My onload callback contains the following:

```
function(response) {

  window.console.log('on load callback...');

      var sequence = Promise.resolve();
      sequence
      .then(function(){
        sleep(10000);
        window.console.log('sleep 1 is over...');
        return 'DONE!';
      })
      .then(function(){
        sleep(10000);
        window.console.log('sleep 2 is over...');
        return 'DONE!';
      })
      .then(function(){
        sleep(10000);
        window.console.log('sleep 3 is over...');
        return 'DONE!';
      });
}
```

And my sleep function is the following:

```
 function sleep(milliseconds) {
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
     if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
       break;
    }
  }
 }
```

In the console it returns:

```
on load callback...
sleep 1 is over...
sleep 2 is over...
sleep 3 is over...
on load callback...
sleep 1 is over...
sleep 2 is over...
sleep 3 is over...
on load callback...
sleep 1 is over...
sleep 2 is over...
sleep 3 is over...
on load callback...
sleep 1 is over...
sleep 2 is over...
sleep 3 is over...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I can understand that the download is blocked when a "sleep" is running, but what I do not get is why it runs all the "sleep 1", "sleep 2" and "sleep 3" before continuing to download the remaining files.

==== EDITS ====

I load the files using a "promisified" XMLHttpRequest and Promise.all(). (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)

Best,
Nicolas

Comment: Where is the code corresponding to the downloading?

Comment: I added the information in the EDITS. There is no magics at all, I used a "promisified" XMLHttpRequest, build my array of sequences for each file then can Promise.all().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're asking here (with this horrible busy-waiting sleep() function that no-one should ever use in real code) is how come all the `.then()` functions take precedence over the `onload` events in the JS event loop?

They do, and it's because promises run on a micro-task queue, which is separate from the main task queue, and drains before the latter.

See also [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146276/timing-of-resolving-of-promises-and-handling-browser-events/28183962#28183962).

Comment: OK that makes sense. I guess that is also a reason why the fetch API appeared as it is fully "promisified"! XHR doesn't play too well with promises it seems.

Answer (score 0):

> but what I do not get is why it runs all the "sleep 1", "sleep 2" and "sleep 3" before continuing to download the remaining files.

Promise callbacks are basically running in arbitrary order<sup>1</sup> when there are multiple promises awaiting to be resolved. In your case, it just chose to run that `sequence` of callbacks (each of which are unfortunately taking very long) before getting back to the `onload` callbacks of your ajax requests that resolve the other promises, and before running their callbacks that continue with the download of the remaining files.

The solution is quite easy: don't use `sleep`, and don't use long-running code (but make it asynchronous).

<sub>1: Of course, callbacks in a chain (`.then(A).then(B)`) need to run in the order of the promises.

And Promises/A+ requires that multiple callbacks on the same promise run in the order of registration (`p.then(A); p.then(B);`).

And ECMAScript6 requires that callbacks on multiple resolved promises run in the order of the promise resolution.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, sleep was just a dummy example to demonstrate the issue. What I was wondering is why it finishes the sequence before starting another sequence. It seems to be because promises and onLoad events are not running in the same task queue, right?

Comment: @Nicolas: Yes, that's a possible explanation; though afaik browsers are not required to process the promise queue first. Surely `sleep` was just a dummy, but what I meant is that you normally won't experience any problems with concurrency as long as all your asynchronously executed snippets are fast (not long-running).